# how to use plot.ts with dates and multiple columns in r

Tags: r, plot, time-series

i have data organized in the following way:

```
>tmp
           L.Income L.2020 L.2030 L.2040 L.2050 G.Fund   F.Fund   C.Fund   S.Fund    I.Fund
2003-06-03        1      1      1      1      1  1.000 1.004012 1.004985 0.999005 0.9950836
2003-06-04        1      1      1      1      1  1.000 1.005015 1.019940 1.014925 1.0009833
2003-06-05        1      1      1      1      1  1.000 1.003009 1.023928 1.024876 1.0108161
2003-06-06        1      1      1      1      1  1.000 1.003009 1.021934 1.019900 1.0196657
2003-06-10        1      1      1      1      1  1.001 1.010030 1.018943 1.013930 1.0147493
2003-06-11        1      1      1      1      1  1.001 1.010030 1.031904 1.026866 1.0314651
```

I would like to create a plot very similar to this but include the dates as the x-axis:

```
>plot.ts(tmp)
```

[image]

I have tried so many things but I keep getting errors (some examples below):

```
> plot.ts(rownames(tmp),tmp)
Error in hasTsp(y) : invalid time series parameters specified
> plot.ts(ts(rownames(tmp)),tmp)
Error in hasTsp(y) : invalid time series parameters specified
```

Comment: `"ts"` class is best for monthly, quarterly and yearly data.  For daily data use zoo or xts packages.

Comment: @G.Grothendieck I have managed to convert my data to an `xts` object. I am still having trouble plotting the data in the same manner as my picture above. I would like the graphs to be all together in that format, or if not possible all in one color-coded graph